# Want to display a Visual notification in my C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to display a Visual Notification blinking for the user in my application .

For Example : Notification in the bottom right corner for the incoming call event ( Like old office assistant wil do fine)

I dont want to use the MsgBox and other things.

Any Idea?

Comment: Where do you want this notification to be displayed? On the taskbar at the *very* bottom of the screen? Or at the bottom of your application's window?

Comment: @cody : Even if i minimize the application , the notification should be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert an notify icon from the tool box and try the following code in any event you want

```
if (WindowState==FormWindowState.Minimized)
{
   BackupMinimizeNotification.Visible = true;
   Hide();
   BackupMinimizeNotification.BalloonTipTitle = "APP Hidden";
   BackupMinimizeNotification.BalloonTipText = "Your application has been minimized to the taskbar.";
   BackupMinimizeNotification.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
}
```